# (ASDF 3) How do you flag a file|component as "dirty" or in need of rebuilding?

Tags: common-lisp, asdf

I would like to tell ASDF that the status of a particular component has changed and it should be recompiled the next time the enclosing system gets loaded.  Motivation: I envision having configuration variables which trigger this process upon being modified.

The necessary tools appear to be in the `asdf/plan` package, if I have to guess.

---

**3 March 2022:** My use of the word 'variables' in my example may have misled @coredump, whose [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67334594/12808416) deals with *environment* variables.  For clarification, what I had in mind was a special variable acting as a compile-time constant for everything downstream of it in the build process.  Modifying it would involve a `setf`-expansion side effect to set the theoretical "dirty" state for the appropriate component tree.

Despite the miscommunication, I'm fairly certain his technique of subclassing `asdf:cl-source-file` and specializing `asdf:operation-done-p`--something I hadn't tried--could still do it.

Answer (score 3):

I tested the following by first adding a new component type that depends on the current value of an environment variable. The package and the definitions are as follows, based on the [Object Model of ASDF](https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf.html#The-object-model-of-ASDF) section of the manual (this depends on *osicat*):

```
(defpackage env-var-asdf
  (:use :cl)
  (:export #:cl-source-file-env-var
           #:depends-on-env-var))

(in-package env-var-asdf)

;; mixin
;;
;; this component depends on a posix environment variable (`varname`) and
;; stores the last known value (`last-value`). AFAIK objects are rebuilt when the 
;; asd file is reloaded, so you can preserve some state in the components if
;; the system definition does not change.
;;
(defclass depends-on-env-var ()
  ((varname :initarg :varname :reader env-var-varname)
   (last-value :accessor env-var-last-value)))

;; this method defines if the operation is already done, we return NIL if
;; the file needs to be recompiled; here, if no last known value exist for the
;; environment variable, or if the current value differs from the last one.
;;
;; I made it an `:around` method but this might be wrong (it never 
;; calls the next method; the behavior depends only on the 
;; environment variable).
;;
(defmethod asdf:operation-done-p :around (operation (component depends-on-env-var))
  (let ((value (osicat-posix:getenv (env-var-varname component))))
    (prog1 (and (slot-boundp component 'last-value)
                (string= value (env-var-last-value component)))
      (setf (env-var-last-value component) value))))

;; a cl-source-file with that mixin being the first superclass,
;; again to prioritize the modified behaviour.
(defclass cl-source-file-env-var (depends-on-env-var asdf:cl-source-file) ())
```

In order to test this, I created `test-asdf` in `quicklisp/local-projects`, with the following `test-asdf.asd` file:

```
(defsystem test-asdf
  :depends-on ()
  :components ((env-var-asdf:cl-source-file-env-var "a"
                :varname "LANG")))
```

Here, component `a` is recompiled/reloaded when the `LANG` environment variable is modified. Here is `a.lisp`:

```
(defpackage :test-asdf (:use :cl))
(in-package :test-asdf)

(print "loaded")
```

In the REPL, when I quickload the system the first time, `"loaded"` is printed to standard output. If I touch the file `a.lisp`, it is reloaded, thought I am not exactly sure why (ASDF is complex), I mean the `input-files` of the components are newer so it might force the recompilation even if `operation-done-p` returns NIL.
Finally, if I don't touch the file but changes the LANG environment variable from within the process, then the file is loaded again.

Comment: I apologise for taking almost a year(!) to answer; I don't get to work on such things as often as I would like.  And I could've been clearer, as in the addendum to my post.  Yours is a good idea, though.

Comment: that's fine no problem :-)